# Difference between using a bed or a sleeping bag in Rust?

Tags: rust

As of now the game contains both the sleeping bag and bed. What are the differences between the two items? If any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Beds** are **more expensive** to craft than sleeping bags, requiring **40 cloth** and **100 metal fragments** (rather than 15 cloth for a sleeping bag). They can only be placed in **a structure with a ceiling** (whereas sleeping bags can be placed anywhere). Once placed, **beds cannot be picked up** (unlike sleeping bags, which can be).

One of the main differences is how **respawning** works. If you respawn at a sleeping bag, you won't be able to respawn at **any other sleeping bag within a 100 metre radius** for at least **four minutes**. If you respawn at a bed, you can't respawn **at that specific bed** for another four minutes. However, **nearby beds aren't affected** by the cooldown, so if there was another bed close by that you had access to, you should still be able to use it to respawn within the four minute window.

Those are the differences that I've read about. But remember, the game is still currently in beta, therefore things might not work exactly as intended.

Comment: Good point on the game being in beta, but possibly more important than 'may not work as intended' is that things may be redesigned or dropped entirely.

Comment: This answer is now outdated.  I'll give it a thumbs up if you update it.